# Springboot doesn't create the database schema

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

i am using `springboot 1.4.4.RELEASE` with mysql database
and the database configuration is as follows:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springboot?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

my main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }

}
```

my entity class (in sub package of main class) :

```
package org.spring.entities;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }



    protected User() {}

    public User(Long id) {
        this.id= id;
    }

    public User(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
                "User[id=%d, firstName='%s', lastName='%s']",
                id, firstName, lastName);
    }

}
```

startup logs:

```
2017-03-25 14:36:34.219  INFO 2816 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-03-25 14:36:34.245  INFO 2816 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2017-03-25 14:36:34.371  INFO 2816 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.11.Final}
2017-03-25 14:36:34.373  INFO 2816 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2017-03-25 14:36:34.375  INFO 2816 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2017-03-25 14:36:34.438  INFO 2816 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2017-03-25 14:36:34.854  INFO 2816 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2017-03-25 14:36:35.610  INFO 2816 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
Hibernate: drop table if exists user
Hibernate: create table user (id bigint not null auto_increment, first_name varchar(255), last_name varchar(255), primary key (id))
2017-03-25 14:36:35.633  INFO 2816 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
2017-03-25 14:36:35.688  INFO 2816 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-03-25 14:36:36.704  INFO 2816 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@4a9c188f: startup date [Sat Mar 25 14:36:30 AST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
```

the issue is that i see in the console that the create queries is generated but the table is not getting created, please advise why i am getting this and how to fix it.

Comment: Why do you think the table hasn't been created? Is there a failure that you haven't shared?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your database url is not preceded with `spring.datasource.url`.

Also you dont seem to have the driver specified:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

And lastly make sure you have that driver as on of your dependencies in your pom.xml

Comment: You don't need a driver because spring detects that for you and next to that specifying the driver is also not needed anymore for JDBC 4.0 (those a registered and detected by default).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue was from the eclipse downloading the artifacts, when i used maven command line to download the artifcats it worked fine !